# Proper syntax for psexec.exe hostname with filename to start

Tags: cmd, command-line, psexec

I'm trying to use psexec.exe to fire up Excel and then use Excel to open a specific .xlsx file.
I've just started learning psexec and I have written commands that work 'incrementally' in order to be sure my initial building blocks were correct along the way.  Decided to actually start with NOTEPAD and a specific TEXT FILE to start:
(Please note, my goal is to execute this process on the local machine, not a remote machine, and for it to be Interactive, thus the -i switch)

**This Works (just opens a blank Notepad window)**

```
"C:\Users\Username\OneDrive - OrgName\Desktop\RunAs Test\psexec.exe" -i -u domain\username -p Password C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

**This does not work - and I am positive the exe path and the file path are correct, I've tried them separately**

```
"C:\Users\Username\OneDrive - OrgName\Desktop\RunAs Test\psexec.exe" -i -u domain\username -p Password C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe \\server\data\mpsc-users\UserName\Test\sadf.txt
```

(**It just returns the boilerplate 3 lines copyright, but with no mention of Error Code or results at all. Nothing else happens**)
[image]

Comment: Hmm. It also says to operate on the local machine you can leave off the machine name entirely.

Answer (score 0):

PsTools.chm is very clear on why it wont work

> "Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be absolute paths on the
> target system)"

```
"psexec.exe" -i \\somewhere.... C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe c:\users\Isaac\desktop\hello.txt
```

**should work** (if the file exists on the remote system)